# Regular expression in JavaScript Adobe Pro XI

Tags: javascript, regex, pdf

I need help using JavaScript in Acrobat Pro XI.
Specifically, I am trying to write a script that will extract the first two letters of a PDF file name and any numbers that immediately follow, including decimals.
I'm attempting to use a regular expression and need help.
I'm new to JavaScript, and have only created simple custom Actions, and can usually only find html java info online.

I would appreciate any help.

> Example: Filename is Ex C-1.2 and I need to return C-1.2.  This will
>   be applied to a folder of PDFs. Thx!

Comment: I'm confused why your pdf files would use `.2` as a file extension? Or if they don't, can you please update your question to include a list of example file names and what exactly from each you need to match?

Comment: Something like this should to the trick: `filename.substring(2).replace(/[0-9 ]*(.*)/g, '$1');`